# Htaccess rewrite redirect numbers and underscores from

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to rewrite the following url

http://example.com/Articles/32423324/this_is_a_test_article
to
http://example.com/Articles/this-is-a-test-article

So far I have tried the following combos (see below all commented out in my htaccess) but none are giving me the desired effects of removing the number directory and changing the underscores to hyphens.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#REMOVE DIRECTORY MADE OF NUMBERS AFTER ARTICLES
#RewriteRule ^Articles/([0-9]+)$ /Articles/ [R=302,L]
#RewriteRule ^Articles/([0-9]+)/$ /Articles/$1 [R=302,L]
#RewriteRule ^Articles/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /Articles/$1 [R=302,L]

#RewriteRule ^Articles/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
#RewriteRule ^Articles/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ Articles/$1 [L,NC,R]
#RewriteRule ^Articles/([0-9]+)/$ Articles/$1 [L,NC,R]
#RewriteRule ^Articles/([0-9]+)/$ /Articles/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(?:\d+/)?([^_]*)_+([^_]*_.*)$ $1/$2-$3 [L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1/$2-$3 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Fantastic - Works Like a charm

Comment: One more question - I have one other url that is like this http://bobodobo.com/blog_news/32423324/this_is_a_test_article and it is not working for it - I presume it is something to do with blog_news having and underscore. It is just not redirecting at all